# Comment upvotes are lost if cast from the Low Quality Posts queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, comments, low-quality-posts, comment-votes

When I choose to <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> while reviewing Low Quality Posts, I try to upvote an existing comment before adding mine.

The problem is that when I do this, all's fine in the queue, but when I go back to the post, the vote is lost.

Comment: This doesn't happen to me upon checking by a) loading the post in a new tab from the link after upvoting the comment or b) refreshing the review result page after returning to it. Just checked.

Comment: Do you use the "back" button on your browser to _"go back to the post"_? Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: A similar 'issue' happened to me - when I got an audit in Triage, and upvoted a comment, it wasn't upvoted afterwards when I went back to the question. Apparently, vote actions during an audit have no effect.

Comment: _And here we see client-side caching in its natural habitat_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized why those comments weren't upvoted.
They were mine.

I didn't look at the author!
They were those I leave when no one is present already.

[image]

There's no bug.
However, you may need to refresh the page sometimes to bypass caching.

Answer (score 18):

> The problem is that when I do this, all's fine in the queue, but when I go back to the post, the vote is lost.

It would happen when you press the back button of the browser after you are directed to a new topic to review. Either refresh the page or open it in a new tab/page to see your changes.